# iPad view layout similar to facebook

Tags: ios, layout, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

How would one go about creating an ipad app that has a similar view layout to the facebook app? That is, one big view in the center, and the smaller, menu-like controller on the left side gets visible when you slide the main view to the right?
Are they using a modified splitview layout, or is this a custom multi-layer layout?

I know that I probably must make use of some gesture recognizers, but can anyone point me into the right direction of how to remake the facebook app layout? E.g what would be the two main controllers (tableview on the left, custom view in fullscreen size in the middle, place above the tableview?), and how do i slide in/out the menu?

Thanks in advance

as a note: I only need landscape orientation, should make thins easier.

[edit] this is my current implementation with the viewdeckcontroller:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

RootViewController* menu = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController* navController= [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menu];

DetailViewController* center = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

IIViewDeckController* rootController = [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:center leftViewController:navController];
_menuController = rootController;

rootController.leftLedge = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 50.0;

self.window.rootViewController = rootController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This is the rootviewcontroller class (left side menu-thing controller):

```
-(void)loadView 
{
//   [super loadView];
   //   self.tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];

   self.view= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 704)];

   UITableView* tableView= [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

   [self.view addSubview:tableView];

   self.tableView= tableView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IIViewDeckController](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) implements sliding views (like in the Path and Facebook apps) and also supports rotation.

Comment: i decided to pick this library, since the other one seems to be iphone only, and also doesnt support landscape orientation.
what i'm having issues with at the moment is the fact that the  lef, table-style viewcontroller (which is hidden under the center view controller) is too wide. i want to make it 320px wide (default tableview width), but i cant seem to get it. both the tableview as well as the navigation bar are too wide. any ideas? (added code above to demonstrate)

Answer (score 2):

This is a drop-in Xcode project for exactly what you want. :)
https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController

Answer (score 0):

I know this could be a bit late.

Hard to be certain this is what you mean but for the width of your left slide out view, you can control how much of it is shown by modifying the leftLedge property to how many pixels from the edge should be covered by the centerViewController. ie. leftLedge=50 would make your left menu 320-50=270 visible, leftLedge=250 would make your left menu 320-250=70 visible. This is visible width not actual width.

In your appDelegate

```
IIViewDeckController *deckController = [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:self.mainNavigationController leftViewController:self.sideMenuViewController];

deckController.panningMode = IIViewDeckNavigationBarPanning;
deckController.leftLedge = 50;
deckController.centerhiddenInteractivity = IIViewDeckCenterHiddenNotUserInteractiveWithTapToClose;
```